# How can I change the "Run as" in a Delta Live Table config, to a service principle?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

We have a DLT pipeline pointing to our code in our `develop` branch. The pipeline should ideally not run as a human user, but rather as a service principle. How can we change that?

Currently it looks as follows (with the Run as being a human user ID):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To run dlt pipeline as service principal you need to add new service principal in admin settings and make that as owner.

Below the default owner of the dlt pipeline, that is as user.

[image]

To change it to service principal, follow below steps.

**Go To** > **App registrations** under **Azure Active Directory**.
There create new app.

[image]

After creating the app copy the **client ID**

[image]

Now, go to **Service principals** under databricks **Admin settings**.
There click **Add service principal**

[image]

You will get below interface.

[image]

Paste the **clientId** you copied earlier in **ApplicatonId** field,
give a name to service principal, check the **Entitlements** and click on **Add**.

After creating **Add service principal** go to your dlt pipeline.
open permissions, delete current user and add service principal with **Is Owner** permission.

[image]

[image]

Now you will get **Run as** having given service principal.

[image]

Next, give notebook manage permission to this service principal, for that go to your notebook under repo and add this principal.

[image]

then

[image]

Now pipeline runs with owner as this service principal.
Even the update started by user it takes owner whatever it assigned in permissions tab.

For more information refer below docs.
[service-principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/service-principals), [Dlt-access-control](https://docs.databricks.com/en/security/auth-authz/access-control/dlt-acl.html).

Comment: Thanks you for the elaborate answer. However, as in the screenshot in my question, I do not see a "Permissions" button in the DLT UI.

Comment: ok you are in admin group? got to admin settings > groups and check in which group you user id is in.

Comment: I am an admin, but still no Permissions button :/